# How to remove pic from placeholder and file from File-Input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image

```
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col s2">
                  <img id="blah" src="img/city.jpg" alt="your image" width="100" height="100"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn red darken-2 z-depth-0" id="RemovePICs" onclick="clearFileInput()" >X</button>
              </div>
              

              <div class="row">
                <div class= "col s10">
                  <form action="#">
                    <div class="file-field input-field">
                      <div class="btn">
                        <span>Profilbild auswählen</span>
                        <input type="file"  id="imgInp" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
```

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function clearFileInput() {
}
```

Hello everyone! I'm creating my own website by using HTML,JS and Materialize-css. I'm also using the File-Input (Materialize-css). If I use the File-Input everything works fine. If I put a pic there, then the pic shows up in the img-placeholder. But now I'm trying to implement a button who removes all (the pic from the placeholder and the file from the file-input). If I click on the X button, everything should look like it did befor. I'm thankful for every help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think as you set `$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);` to image. you need to use same code but set `src` blank. Try the below snippet.

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
    
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
    
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});

function clearFileInput() {
    $('#blah').attr('src','');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s2">
        <img id="blah" src="img/city.jpg" alt="your image" width="100" height="100"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn red darken-2 z-depth-0" id="RemovePICs" onclick="clearFileInput()" >X</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class= "col s10">
        <form action="#">
            <div class="file-field input-field">
                <div class="btn">
                    <span>Profilbild auswählen</span>
                    <input type="file"  id="imgInp" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">
                </div>
                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please stop nagging people with comments asking "Does my answer help?" or "check my edits". The person who asked the question is already notified that you've posted an answer.

Comment: @meagar sorry if it's nagging. but I am just making sure the person who asked the question is got a solution or not.